# Creating a Callback URL

Tags: python, api, zapier, callbackurl

Apologies for my ignorance.
I am a data analyst in a small organisation (no data engineer/architect/web developer) and I am trying to set up a connection to an API with a company whose software/app we have purchased.
They have stated that for them to set up access to their API i need to create a callback url.
I don't really know where to start with this and neither does the IT manager.
I will likely be using Zapier or Power Automate to build the workflow needed but not sure how to go about setting up the callbackurl as requested. there last response was

> 'we would need a callback URL or local host to be able to generate API key'

any guidance would be great